# Transform data from rows to columns using SQL

Tags: sql, pivot, window-functions

**Description of data structure**

Suppose we have a table of order items (i.e. one row represents a single order item). Each order item has `product_type` ('A' or 'B'), `amount`, and `currency`.
One order (`order_id`) can contain 1..4 order items. In one order, there can be one currency (such order consists of 1..2 order items) or two currencies (such order consists of 2..4 order items).

I need to transform this into a table of orders (i.e. one row represents a single order). I'm new to [SQL window functions](https://www.sqltutorial.org/sql-window-functions/), so any hint would be highly appreciated.

**Example**

Original data structure:

```
| order_id | product_type | amount | currency |
| 1        | A            | 2      | USD      |             
| 1        | A            | 1      | EUR      |
| 1        | B            | 6      | USD      |
| 1        | B            | 5      | EUR      |
| 2        | A            | 7      | USD      |
| 2        | B            | 5      | USD      |
| 2        | B            | 3      | CAD      |
| 3        | A            | 2      | USD      |
| 3        | B            | 4      | AUD      |
| 4        | A            | 1      | NZD      |
| 4        | B            | 2      | NZD      |
| 5        | A            | 8      | EUR      |
```

Target data structure:

```
| order_id | a_amount1 | a_cur1 | a_amount2 | a_cur2 | b_amount1 | b_cur1 | b_amount2 | b_cur2 |
| 1        | 2         | USD    | 1         | EUR    | 6         | USD    | 5         | EUR    |
| 2        | 7         | USD    |           |        | 5         | USD    | 3         | CAD    |
| 3        | 2         | USD    |           |        | 4         | AUD    |           |        |
| 4        | 1         | NZD    |           |        | 2         | NZD    |           |        |
| 5        | 8         | EUR    |           |        |           |        |           |        |
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can try a pivot query with the help of `ROW_NUMBER` to generate the series used to distinguish currencies:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY order_id, product_type ORDER BY currency) rn
    FROM yourTable
)

SELECT
    order_id,
    MAX(CASE WHEN product_type = 'A' AND rn = 1 THEN amount END)   AS a_amount1,
    MAX(CASE WHEN product_type = 'A' AND rn = 1 THEN currency END) AS a_cur1,
    MAX(CASE WHEN product_type = 'A' AND rn = 2 THEN amount END)   AS a_amount2,
    MAX(CASE WHEN product_type = 'A' AND rn = 2 THEN currency END) AS a_cur2,
    MAX(CASE WHEN product_type = 'B' AND rn = 1 THEN amount END)   AS b_amount1,
    MAX(CASE WHEN product_type = 'B' AND rn = 1 THEN currency END) AS b_cur1,
    MAX(CASE WHEN product_type = 'B' AND rn = 2 THEN amount END)   AS b_amount2,
    MAX(CASE WHEN product_type = 'B' AND rn = 2 THEN currency END) AS b_cur2
FROM cte
GROUP BY
    order_id
ORDER BY
    order_id;
```

### Demo

Comment: Just one minor thing: b_* column aliases should be there for product_type = 'B' cases. But the logic works fine, will test further with a larger dataset. Thank you Tim for a great lesson!